# Finding Min Value Filtering Two Columns

Tags: dax, powerpivot

In PowerPivot I'm trying find the Min value in a table based on two column values. My data contains multiple people, on multiple dates with multiple segments of time. For each person on each date I need to determine the earliest segment of time in the data.

I was able to use this in data on a daily basis and it works fine but when I add multiple days to the data it only locates the minimum segment of time for each person, not each person for each date listed.

```
=
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( [start] ),
        FILTER ( actual, [Agent_User_Name] = EARLIER ( [Agent_User_Name] ) )
    )
        = [start],
    TRUE (),
    FALSE ()
)
```

---

```
    Agent_User_Name     date      start
    Susan               1/1/19    08:00
    Susan               1/1/19    08:45
    Susan               1/1/19    10:00
    Susan               1/2/19    08:30
    Susan               1/2/19    09:00
    Timothy ....
```

I am trying to determine that Susan's earliest time on 1/1/19 was 08:00, on 1/2/19 was 08:30 and mark that record as true or false for earliest time.

Comment: I think you should group on the date. I don't know this ramework you are using, but I would grouf if i could use SQL

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a calculated column:

```
=
VAR Min_Time =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Actual[Start] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( Actual, Actual[Agent_User_Name], Actual[date] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( Actual[Start] = Min_Time, TRUE (), FALSE () )
```

Here, for each row we find min start in the entire start column (that's why we use ALL), but keeping current row's Agent_User_Name and Date filters (that's why EXCEPT). In effect, it groups the start column by current user and date.

Result:

[image]

---

You can also make it a dynamic measure:

```
=
MINX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        Actual,
        Actual[Agent_User_Name],
        Actual[date],
        "Min_Time", MIN ( Actual[start] )
    ),
    [Min_Time]
)
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit:**

VAR works for Excel 2016 or later. If you have older versions of Excel, re-write the formula without variables:

```
= IF (
        Actual[Start]
            = CALCULATE (
                MIN ( Actual[Start] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( Actual, Actual[Agent_User_Name], Actual[date] )
            ),
        TRUE (),
        FALSE ()
    )
```

Not as clean and readable as with VAR, but should work. If you can, switch to Excel 2016 as soon as possible - Power Pivot engine is much better.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. In trying to create the calculated column I get an error that the syntax for Min_Time is incorrect using the code below:                                            
```=
 VAR Min_Time =
              CALCULATE(
                     MIN(actual[start]),
                     ALLEXCEPT(actual,actual[ï»¿Agent_User_Name],actual[Date])
          )
RETURN
         IF( actual[start] = Min_Time, True(), False() )```

Comment: Thanks very much. That worked for eXcel 2013. I've asked for 2016 and been rebuffed by have access to Office 365 which includes version 16.x so I'll try that. Thanks again.